# I want to have customized keyboard pressing sound

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, keyboard

I have a pretty weird question: I want that whenever I press a key in the keyboard a typewriter-esque key-press sound will be played. How can I achieve it? I obviously prefer the simplest solution.

Comment: There will likely be no sound-assignable keyboard key press events in the audio settings. But you could check out the settings for handicapped people (don't know its english name; in DE it's "Eingabehilfen"). Maybe there is a assignable sound for key press actions for blind users.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss thanks Tobias, but do you know where in "Eingabehilfen" (Google gave a good-enough translation) is that option? I can only find "Toggle Keys - Hear a sound when you press NUM LOCK, CAPS LOCK or SCROLL LOCK".

Comment: I said "maybe". Maybe there isn't such an option at all.

Answer (score 0):

Appearently, there's and old little software called ClicKey which does this.
https://www.grc.com/freeware/clickey.htm